# npm ERR! code UNKNOWN npm ERR! syscall mkdir

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm

I have run `npm install && npm run dev`

and I get this error.

```
npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\24\db
npm ERR! errno -4094
npm ERR! UNKNOWN: unknown error, mkdir 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\24\db'
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm ERR! code UNKNOWN
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\24\db
npm ERR! errno -4094
npm ERR! UNKNOWN: unknown error, mkdir 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\24\db'
```

I have tried

`npm cache verify`, `npm cache clear --force`.
but nothing change

I have uninstalled and installed the js node again. but nothing :(

What should I do ?
i use window 10 64-bit

Comment: try running npm init first to create a project run npm init then that creates the project, then you can install packages and make files. I recommend making a core file e.g. echo.>app.js then you can do npm install (package) --save

Comment: may be a permission issue. try with admin prompt.

Comment: This may be due to a permission issue. Do you have a way to reproduce this problem? Is this a new project or an existing project?

Comment: if you are using vagrant with the homestead box, maybe you are having the same issue https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/1239 try to install npm in your host machine, and there run that commands

Comment: I still can't handle it :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, I tried the same steps as you to install mongoDB in my application, without success. So I opened the prompt in administrator mode and put the following path: **C:\foo\target_folder> npm install mongodb** and it worked! :)